# c array not assigning correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm assigning an array to a pointer, but after the assignment, I print the values of both but they are different. Also, the pointer values change from execution to execution (and since the values come from an static file, that looks like the pointer is not assigned and it's printing address directions).

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct machine {
    int neighborhood;
    int location;
    int* capacities;
    int* safety_capacities;
    int* moving_costs;
};
struct resource{
    int transient;
    int weight_load_cost;
};
struct variables{
    int resources_amount;
    int machines_amount;

    struct machine* machines;
    struct resource* resources;
};
struct variables var;

void read_resources(FILE *file){
    int resources_amount, i;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    getline(&line, &len, file);
    //printf("resources: %s", line);
    resources_amount = atoi(line);

    struct resource resources[resources_amount];

    for(i = 0; i<resources_amount; i++){
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        //printf("transient: %s\n", line);
        resources[i].transient = atoi(line);
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        //printf("load_cost: %s\n", line);
        resources[i].weight_load_cost = atoi(line);
    }
    var.resources = resources;
    var.resources_amount = resources_amount;
}
void read_machines(FILE *file){
    int machines_amount, i, j, num, length;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    getline(&line, &len, file);
    //printf("machines: %d\n", atoi(line));
    machines_amount = atoi(line);

    struct machine machines[machines_amount];

    printf("Printing array values:\n");
    for(i=0; i<machines_amount; i++){
        //blank line
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        //getting neighborhood
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        machines[i].neighborhood = atoi(line);
        //getting location
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        machines[i].location = atoi(line);
        //getting capacities
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        int capacities[var.resources_amount];

        for(j=0; j < var.resources_amount; j++){
            sscanf( line, "%d%n", &num, &length);
            capacities[j]=num;
            printf("Machine %d, resource %d: %d\n", i, j, capacities[j]);
            line += length;
        }

        //HERE IS THE ERROR I GUESS!! <---
        machines[i].capacities = capacities;
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        int safety_capacities[var.resources_amount];
        for(j=0; j < var.resources_amount; j++){
            sscanf( line, "%d%n", &num, &length);
            safety_capacities[j]=num;
            //printf( "Number %d is %d\n", j, num );
            line += length;
        }
        machines[i].safety_capacities = safety_capacities;
        getline(&line, &len, file);
        int moving_costs[machines_amount];
        //printf("Moving Costs:\n");
        for(j=0; j < machines_amount; j++){
            //sscanf( line, "%d%n", &num, &length);
            moving_costs[j]=num;
            //printf( "Number %d is %d\n", j, num );
            line += length;
        }
        machines[i].moving_costs = moving_costs;
    }
    printf("Printing pointer values:\n");
    for(i=0; i < machines_amount; i++){
        for(j=0; j < var.resources_amount; j++){
            printf("Machine %d, resource %d: %d\n", i, j, machines[i].capacities[j]);
        }
    }

    var.machines = machines;
    var.machines_amount = machines_amount;
}
void read_file(char *filename){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if ( file == 0 ){
        printf( "Could not open Settings File\n" );
    }
    else{
        read_resources(file);
        read_machines(file);
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    read_file(argv[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

The input file is:

```
2

1
10

0
100
4

0
0
30 400
16 80
0 1 4 5

0
0
10 250
8 160
1 0 3 4

1
1
15 100
12 80
4 3 0 2

1
2
10 100
8 80
5 4 2 0
2

2
0

1
1
0
3

0
12 10
1000

0
10 20
100

1
6 200
1
1
0 1 20
10
1
10
100
```

and the executing code is:

`./mrp -t 1000 -p test_instance -i mrp_original_sol -o mrp_sol -s 10`

Comment: Could you reduce this mountain to a SSCCE ?

Comment: *"...it's printing address directions"* Whats that?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a reference to the array `machines`, which is local to the function `read_machines()`. Once that function exits, the array ceases to exist and the stored pointer no longer points to anywhere valid. Dereferencing that pointer causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! finally i can understand what's going on there

Comment: The last question, how can i create and instantiate a struct with multiple arrays of undefined size? something like this:


    struct store{
       struct clients[];
       struct items[];
    }


i tried it with the pointers approach that you see in my question, but with your answer it seems like the wrong approach